# Copy and Paste Macro on loop within same sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macos, copy-paste

I am trying to copy cells B48:B52 and then paste in cells B55:B59, and then paste the same data again but with two rows in between (so now in cells B62:B66). Need to do this in a loop so that it pastes the range ~1100 times.

I'm sure there is a way to do this with VBA but cannot figure it out. Any helpers?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Sub paste_each_n()

t = 48
Count = 1

Do Until Count = 1100

Range("B" & t & ":B" & t + 4).Copy
Cells(t + 7, 2).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
t = t + 7
Count = Count + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. Now trying to copy and paste formulas from cells C43:K47 to cells C50:K55 on the same loop with 2 blank rows in between again. I modified the script above as the following, but it pastes the formulas shifted one column to the left. How do I fix? 

Sub FormulaCopyPaste()
'
' FormulaCopyPaste Macro
'

'
       t = 43
Count = 1

Do Until Count = 5

Range("C" & t & ":K" & t + 4).Copy
Cells(t + 7, 2).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
t = t + 7
Count = Count + 1

Loop

End Sub

Comment: try changing this: Cells(t + 7, 2).Select to: Cells(t + 7, 3).Select